# Automatically restore Texstudio session on startup

Tags: texstudio

Is there an option to restore automatically the last session on startup with Texstudio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. From the menu bar: `Options` -> `Automatically Restore Session at Next Start`. Tested on TeXstudio 2.8.0, Mac OS X.

**Update** TeXStudio 2.10.8

This newer version (on Mac OS X) has the setting in a different place. From the menu bar, select `TeXstudio` -> `Preferences`. In the new window, tick the box `Show Advanced Options` if not already selected. Then in the `General` category, under the heading `Session`, there is the option `Restore Previous Session at Startup`.

Comment: Yes, that works. I could not find it in the user manual. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that works with windows, TeXstudio 2.10.2.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 2.10.8 (tested on Windows, but likely true on other platforms), the option has moved to `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `General` -> `Session` -> `Restore Previous Session at Startup`

(I appreciate that this is now quite an old question, but the answer has recently changed)

Answer (score 1):

In 2.12.6 this option is selected by default.

If someone has switched it off do the following in the Windows/Linux version of TeXStudio:

- Menu `Options` → `Configure TeXstudio`,
- now switch on `Show Advanced Options` (at the bottoms),
- → `General`,
- now switch on `Restore Previous Session at Startup`.

To switch it off do the same but in the last step switch off `Restore Previous Session at Startup`.